Filtering with mongoose find and populate two different models
I have two collections, one is Update and one is trainee.
The trainee one has some fields and one of them is gender. Trainee has a key personalDetails and a nested key gender.
Basically I want to filter by gender (trainee.personalDetails.gender).
Right now, I try to filter by gender but get an empty array instead.
const getUpdates = async (request: any, reply: FastifyReply) => {
  const { coachId }: { coachId: string } = request.user;
  const {
    page,
    limit,
    status,
    escortId,
    gender,
    sort,
  }: {
    page: number;
    limit: number;
    status: string | null;
    escortId: string | null;
    gender: string | null;
    sort?: 'asc' | 'desc';
  } = request.query;

  let coach: CoachType | null;
  try {
    coach = await Coach.findById(coachId);
  } catch (err: Error | any) {
    logger.error(`can't get coach by his id: ${err.message} - ${coachId}`);
    return await replyErr(
      reply,
      500,
      'Getting updates failed, please try again.',
    );
  }

  if (!coach) {
    logger.error(`didn't find coach by his id - ${coachId}`);
    return await replyErr(reply, 404, 'Could not find coach for provided id.');
  }

  const query: Record<string, any> = {
    coach: coachId,
    status: { $regex: status ?? '' },
  };

  if (escortId) {
    query.escort = escortId;
  }

  if (gender) {
    query['trainee.personalDetails.gender'] = { $regex: gender, $options: 'i' };
  }

  let updatesQueryPromise: any;
  let updates: any = [];
  try {
    updatesQueryPromise = Update.find(query).populate({
      path: 'trainee',
      select: 'name personalDetails.gender',
    });

    const sortDirection = sort === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
    updates = await updatesQueryPromise
      .skip((page - 1) * limit)
      .limit(limit)
      .sort({ createdAt: sortDirection });
  } catch (err: Error | any) {
    logger.error(`can't get updates - ${coachId}`, err);
    return await replyErr(
      reply,
      500,
      'Getting updates failed, please try again.',
    );
  }


You didn't show the schema, but since that code populates the "trainee" field of the "Update" model, it is probably a safe assumption that the "trainee" field contains the _id of a document in the trainee collection.
This would mean that the field 'trainee.personalDetails.gender' does not exist in the document stored in the updates collection, so the query is correct that no documents match the regex provided in the query.
If you want to filter that server side you could used a $lookup stage to fetch the trainee data prior to matching on gender.
